# Anypoint Studio 7 Installation issue java not found

Tags: java, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

I am trying to setup Anypoint 7.3 on my machine . I have installed jdk and followed all the steps but still on trying to start Anypoint i get an error that JDK must be installed.

This is my config

```
-vmargs
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\javaw.exe
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

NOTE : SOLUTION  - i know its stupid but this resolved my issue.. in ini file i had to put my -vm javapath before the --vmargs
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM line.. Hope this helps someone

Comment: What are your `classpath` variables ? If you can share.

Comment: JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201

Comment: Have you added `PATH` variable too for java ?

Comment: Keep `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin` for `PATH` variable and try again once you reboot the system.

Answer (score 0):

Update your environment variable  PATH as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin. It should fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Current version of Studio (7.6.0, as of today) comes bundled with AdoptOpenJDK8.  So, you do not need to install a separate JDK, or edit the Studio's ini file. Simply download, extract and start the Studio.  It should open up without needing any more changes.